# Extensions to distributed Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

In the conclusions of the paper for [distributed Stochastic Gradient Descent using mini-batches](https://www.google.de/url?q=http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/158712/distr_mini_batch.pdf&sa=U&ei=BrcsVZnUKs73auyigfAF&ved=0CCQQFjAI&usg=AFQjCNGxs3dMrb65inAL4VjQinfSMljO8w) the authors discuss a problem of the proposed method regarding the synchrony requirements.

Specifically, they talk about the requirement that all gradients need to be taken at same prediction point, and that has performance implications for async systems. One proposed solution is to allow nodes to accumulate gradients at different but close points.

The claim that under the smoothness assumption this should work, since gradients of close points should be similar.

Do you think this assumption is correct?

I haven't been able to find any literature that investigated this idea, any idea of papers that have tried to implement this?

Comment: You should post the name of the paper you are referring.

Comment: Sorry for that, added it now.